# In psychophysics, why are log luminance rather than absolute luminance values reported?

Tags: perception, vision, psychophysics, sensory-perception

Are there any papers which justify converting into log luminance? For example papers showing humans being sensitive to changes in log luminance rather than luminance *per se*?

Answer (score 5):

In general, subjective sensation increases linearly with the the log of physical intensity, which is described by [Fechner's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law).

We are sensitive to small variations when light is dim, but we need large differences in intensity under conditions of high luminance ([Weber's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law)). This is a linear relation, but taken together with Fechner these findings are described as the widely-known [Weber-Fechner's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law), justifying the log scales used.

Another well-known example is the [decibel scale](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/dB.htm) in hearing, which is also a log scale.

Any basic textbook on perception or psychophysics will explain this and a reference is added below.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Masin *et al.*, *J History Behav Sci* (2009); **45**(1): 56–65](http://www.psy.unipd.it/~masin/Masin-2009d.pdf)</sub>